# Can someone explain the meaning of this quote?

Tags: quotations

‘In the end, it’s not the years in your life that count, It’s the life in your years.’             - Abraham Lincoln

Comment: Note: there doesn't seem to be any evidence that Lincoln said this. http://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/07/14/life-years-count/

Comment: It's not how much time you have, but what you do with your time that matters.

Comment: imagine you were a dog - you only get to live for 14years, but it feels like 98:)

Comment: A great way to say that age alone doesn't make you any wiser!

Comment: **"I never said that. Don't believe everything you read on the internet." - Abraham Lincoln.**

Comment: "_It's not the one who said it that counts, it's the meaning_" - Abraham Lincoln (apocryphal)

Answer (score 1):

"*It is not your age that counts, but what you did in your life*"

How true!

Answer (score 0):

What matters is if you lead a fulfilling life other than many years of life without fruitful moments. To sum it, what matters is the quality in those years, and not the quantity of years spent living.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about how much you lived, but it is always how you lived. Life is all about  living in present moment. Life is all about experiences you got throughout your living.

Imagine you are telling your grandchildren about your superb thriller experience back in your old days.  While telling that, you will actually live those moments. Right?

That's what the quote says, 
‘In the end, it’s not the years in your life that count, It’s the life in your years.’ - Abraham Lincoln